# Jetpack Compose TextOverflow.Clip not working as expected

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm rendering a long text in a Text composable. I would like to detect the last displayed line and character.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Text(
  longText,
  overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
  onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
      val lastLineIndex = textLayoutResult.lineCount - 1
      val lastCharacterIndex = textLayoutResult.getLineEnd(lastLineIndex, visibleEnd = true)
      ...
  }
)
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. The last line is displayed but cut in half, I would have expected this to be clipped altogether
2. the lastLineIndex and lastCharacterIndex refer to the whole longText rendering, not just the portion that fits without overflow (e.g. lastLineIndex is 1000 instead of 14)

If I use TextOverflow.Ellipsis it works as I would expect (last line that was previously only half rendered is removed and the indices refer to the visible part of the text). However I don't want to have the ... at the end.

I thought Clip works like Ellipsis, just not showing the ... Is that understanding not correct?